# Resolve missing permissions require by GoogleMaps.setMyLocationEnalbled

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google maps to show my Office location inside Fragment. When I compile and run the application, It shows the maps but doesn't mark my location.

and on fragment java file, `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

is been underlined by red color and I don't know how to solve it.

Below is my code from Fragment maps.

```
public class maps extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private Context mContext;
    private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private MarkerOptions currentPositionMarker = null;
    private Marker currentLocationMarker;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mContext = getActivity();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mContext = getActivity();

        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();/// getChildFragmentManager();
        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
        if (supportMapFragment == null) {
            supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map_container, supportMapFragment).commit();
        }
        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        /*map.setOnMapLongClickListener(MapyFragment.this);
        map.setOnMapClickListener(MapFragment.this);*/
    }

    public void updateCurrentLocationMarker(Location currentLatLng){

        if(map != null){

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatLng.getLatitude(),currentLatLng.getLongitude());
            if(currentPositionMarker == null){
                currentPositionMarker = new MarkerOptions();

                currentPositionMarker.position(latLng)
                        .title("My Location").
                        icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_facebook_3));
                currentLocationMarker = map.addMarker(currentPositionMarker);
            }

            if(currentLocationMarker != null)
                currentLocationMarker.setPosition(latLng);

            ///currentPositionMarker.position(latLng);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not want to display your location, just remove map.setMyLocationEnabled. Using a marker to mark you office location

Comment: When posting code online or sharing with third party, make sure you do not post keys along with the code. You've posted your google maps api key along with the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

For the current location, you find the best solution with the proper example you find below google official document. Try it your self it will explore you.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-places-tutorial?hl=pt-br

Comment: I don't want to display the current location. Instead I would like to show my office location and mark it..

Comment: You specified map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);, So I suggested you about current location, For your office location you need to specify your office latitude-longitude.

Comment: After specifying lat-long you can move your map camera on that particular lat-long.